# Inserting PHP DB result into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can i insert PHP db result query to a javascript array. I have set of values in my Database and I want to get those values and store it in a javascript array. This is my query

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM members");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['names'];
}
```

And I want to store it in a javascript array like this

```
var names = ['John','Chris','Leo'];
```

This is my code but im getting an error.

```
var names = [
    <?php while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo $row['skill']; 
    } ?>
];
```

Comment: You need to quote the strings and separate them with a comma.

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead.

```
$names = [];

<?php while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $names[] = $row['skill']; 
}

$javaScriptArray = json_encode($names);

?>
```

JavaScript is run on the browser while PHP is run on the server.  They don't really integrate with each other.  To make the array available in javascript do something like this.

```
<script>
    var arr = <?php echo $javaScriptArray; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I am still a newbie

Comment: @JkAsentista No problem.  Everyone learns by making mistakes!  If my answer solved your problem just mark it as accepted so other people can see!